# Need background image to become responsive

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have set a background image. I need that to be responsive. I have used media queries for that, but the image is the same. Should I use background-size or width and height to view it?
As in it gets cropped off. I tried the background-size:100% 100%, but it looks stretched.

The code is given below:

```
.header-area {
    position: fixed;
    background: url(images/image.jpg)  no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.overlay {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.overlay:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #000000;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Comment: You used the same URL each time!

Comment: it's the same image that I want to put. My image remains the same. the thing is, the image is cropped off when viewed in mobile

Comment: You said that the problem was that it was the same image.

Comment: yaa, as in its the same image. my background image is just a picture. when its viewed in different devices, apart from desktop the image gets cropped.

Comment: Have you read what `cover` does? If you don't want it cropped, why are you using `cover`?

Comment: is there a way to post images, so that i could show you how it is, so that its clear.

Comment: i understand what cover does, but when i change it there's an issue over there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make `background-size: cover` and `background-position: center`

```
.header-area { 
     background-image: url("image url");
     height: 100%; 

     /* Center and scale the image nicely */
     background-position: center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you.
I've found the answer.

just needed to modify the code a bit.

```
.header-area {
    position: fixed;
    background: url(images/image.jpg)  no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

removed the media query and used this.